# Percent difference between accuracy of two machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have trained two machine learning models. Both have slightly different accuracies.

```
Model-A Accuracy = 0.78 or 78%

Model-B Accuracy = 0.80 or 80%
```

Can I infer from the above results that `Model-B` is `2%` better than `Model-A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how you evaluate the models, and on target distribution.

#### Metric

If distribution of classes is not balanced, accuracy might not be as useful to describe the generalization error. Use [ROC AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) or [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).

#### Evaluation process

[Cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) will give you more robust estimation of the evaluation metric than hold-out validation. Stratified Cross-validation is even better for the unbalanced dataset.

If you're confident in your validation method, then yes, you can iterpret the results in the way you described: `Model-B` is `2%` better than `Model-A`.

It's still only an estimate, after all. You can use bootstrapping to estimate confidence intervals, select threshold and infer whether the difference is statistically significant.